# SharePoint 2013 search refinement not showing Pdf, Word in the FilterType

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 search site. It has a refinement webpart but shows only two Result type under it:

1. SharePoint Site
2. Web Page

[image: Result Type showing only two options]

I would like to add more result types in the Refinement webpart like PDF, Excel or PowerPoint so that I would filter my results.

Please see the screenshot below as this is what I see when I edit the webpart and click on 'Choose Refiners'.

[image]

Does the Filetype (in the Refinement) display only those files under the ResultType that have been indexed or crawled?

Is there something I need to do to add more file types such as PDF or Word doc under the Result Type?

Please reply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refiner will show only crawled items result types and which are available for you.
 
So even if SharePoint crawled PDF document please make sure that you have permissions to open it.

Also refiner template has implemented conversion for most well known file types into their names (doc, docx => Word).

But if you expect to see other result types in refiner (Word, Excel, etc.), please check crawl log if all items were crawled successfully.